# screenshot of html file on iPhone to photo library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app on the iphone which will display on the screen an html file containing text and an image.  I manipulate this html file with javascript and when I'm done I would like the user to be able to take a screen shot but would like it to be done automatically, without pressing the home and power buttons.  Is the some javascript or jQuery  that, once the final screen is displayed on the phone, automatically takes a screen shot and places it into the photo library on the phone?  Thanks.

Comment: tell the user: `You know something awesome happens when you try to go to the home page and lock the device at the same time? It goes to an awesome "lock home" screen. Try it!`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Longer answer: Kinda, but not really.

As far as I know, you cannot make iOS take a screenshot nor even download an image through Javascript or similar. However, I guess you could try to [draw the DOM in a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) and then use `canvas.toDataURL()` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement)) to convert it into an image. You could then instruct the user to hold down their finger on the image to bring up the save dialogue and save it to their device.

As I said, not really a pretty solution, but perhaps something you could experiment with if you really need this feature.

Edit: I did a fast Google search and found [this javascript library](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) that should make it a bit easier to do what I described above.